# Can't use google play service “Failed to fetch the following dependencies: com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:X” when force resolve after import

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I've created an Android app and I am trying to set up Google Play services as I want to use the leader board etc.

I downloaded and imported the latest plugin "`GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.50` " and had no errors during the import.

I then go to `assets/ play service resolver/android/force` resolve and run that.

After running I end up with the following error:

> Resolution failed
>
> Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
>
> com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.9.50
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>
> Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
>
> GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
>
> GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
>
> GooglePlayServices.c_AnonStorey18:<>m_26(List`1)
>
> GooglePlayServices.c_AnonStorey14:<>m_1F(Result)
>
> GooglePlayServices.c_AnonStorey15:<>m_28()
>
> GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
>
> UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

If I ignore the error and compile the app it works fine but does not connect to the Google service. I can publish and use the app without crashes etc but I can't log on to Google or view leader boards.

I am using: `unity 2017.1.1f1 personal 64bit`

`Windows 10 64 bit`

`jdk1.8.0_162`

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with the workaround given in this [thread](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2012).

> - Reimported Google Play Games Plugin (It will select the missing files by default).
> - Go to Assets menu => Play Services Resolver => Android Resolver => Force Resolve.
> - After resolving dependencies , Resolve Conflict window pops up. Click NO.
> - Build and Test your application
>
> Add Debug.Log to check your authenticate status.
>
> ```
> Social.localUser.Authenticate (success => {
>     if (success) {
>         Debug.Log ("SignIn successful");
>     } else {
>         Debug.Log ("SignIn failed");
>     }
> });
> ```

Here are some additional references:

- [Resolution fails everytime trying to fetch gpgs-plugin-support](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2094)
- [Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2048)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this. when doing the force resolve i get the Failed to Fetch error.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml file and make sure that the path mentioned for `"com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:x.x.xx"` exists and is valid. Then try Force Resolve again.

Comment: Hi  .... GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml --->>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dependencies>
<!-- Internal library dependency generated at build time. 
    It also defines the transitive dependencies on play-services
-->
  <androidPackages>
    <androidPackage spec="com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.9.50">
      <repositories>
        <repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository</repository>
      </repositories>
    </androidPackage>
  </androidPackages>
</dependencies>

Comment: if i go to "Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository"  the folder only contains a folder named "COM" and a file named "com.meta".  should this be where i need to have my "gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.50" files ??